# How to get RGB material output for points in the UV coordinate space with blender Python?

Tags: python, materials, node-editor

I would like to get the RGB output of a material at specific UV coordiantes. Is this possible to do with Blender Python?

So basically I have a plane with a procedural material applied, and then I would specify a UV coordinate to a function and the output of that function would be the RGB value of the applied procedural material at those specified UV coordinates. I am looking for that function.

Thank you!

Comment: You can use Python to create a temporary scene with a light, camera, plane using the material, render the scene, read the pixel value. You will have to use some arbitrary data, for example the resolution and sampling rate may drastically change the value of a given pixel in some cases... 

Comment: Maybe baking the material with an emissive shader would achieve that ? You can't do it in realtime though I'm afraid